# Python Async API Wrapper, how to structure it

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

Currently I have a wrapper project for an API service. Currently using a class that gets instantiated and then all endpoints are accessed through methods on the class and then data is returned as a Python dictionary. Here's an example:

```
class APIProject:
    def __init__(self, api_key, useragent="MyUserAgent"):
        self.url = f"https://api.server.io/v1"
        self._api_key = api_key
        self._useragent = useragent
        self._headers = {"X-API-Key": self._api_key, "accept": "application/json", "User-Agent": self._useragent}

    def get_endpoint1(self, arg1, arg2):
        endpoint = "/endpoint1"
        response = requests.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2}, headers=self._headers)
        return response.json()

    def get_endpoint2(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
        endpoint = "/endpoint2"
        response = requests.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2, "arg3": arg3, "arg4": arg4}, headers=self._headers)
        return response.json()
```

I would like to make an async version, using aiohttp.

How would you structure this on a similar way? aiohttp frequently goes using context managers instead, compared to requests.

Any project with a similar approach you can point me to?

Comment: Yes I did, but I wanted to see a few examples on how people tackled this when making API rest wrappers. aiohttp needs to create a session first, maybe one per website you are handling. And that can be done through a context manager that automatically closes the session, or maybe just closing the session manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make your class a context manager that wraps the client session. See, for example:
https://github.com/mlowijs/tesla_api

That one just calls `.close()` in the exit method, but you could even just call the client context methods directly:

```
    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self._client.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, ...):
        await self._client.__aexit__(...)
```