# unclosed session when not using a context manager

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

I built this api wrapper based on https://github.com/mlowijs/tesla_api as suggested by a member of this community as an example/boiler plate on [Python Async API Wrapper, how to structure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041234/python-async-api-wrapper-how-to-structure-it).

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class AsyncWrapper:
    def __init__(self, api_key, useragent="API-Wrapper/0.2"):
        self.url = f"https://example.api/v1"
        self._api_key = api_key
        self._useragent = useragent
        self._headers = {"X-API-Key": self._api_key, "accept": "application/json", "User-Agent": self._useragent}
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self.close()

    async def close(self):
        await self._session.close()

    async def get_endpoint1(self, arg1, arg2):
        endpoint = "/pair"

        async with self._session.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2}, headers=self._headers) as response:
            return await response.json()
    
    async def get_endpoint2(self, arg1, arg2, optionalarg1=None, optionalarg2=None):
        endpoint = "/token"

        async with self._session.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2, "optionalarg1": optionalarg1, "optionalarg2": optionalarg2}, headers=self._headers) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

The class is done using asynchronous context managers (`__aenter__` `__aexit__`) to create and kill the session as shown here. However, a `close()` method is left there so it can be called to close the session in case the class wasn't instantiated using a context manager:

```
class AsyncWrapper:
    def __init__(self, api_key, useragent="API-Wrapper/0.2"):
        self.url = f"https://example.api/v1"
        self._api_key = api_key
        self._useragent = useragent
        self._headers = {"X-API-Key": self._api_key, "accept": "application/json", "User-Agent": self._useragent}
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self.close()

    async def close(self):
        await self._session.close()
```

When running this code initiating the object, and then closing the session explictly by using the `close()` method that I left in the class:

```
import asyncio
import AsyncWrapper

api_key = "my_key"

async def main():
    client = AsyncWrapper(api_key)

    response1 = await client.get_endpoint1("argument1", "argument2")
    print(response1)

    await client.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I get this output claiming unclosed client session. However, the session was explictly closed at the end. After this warning, the output proceeds as normal.

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000028D1F0E0390>
```

However, if I run the same code using a context manager. There's no "unclosed client session" warning:

```
import asyncio
import AsyncWrapper

api_key = "my_key"

async def main():
    async with AsyncWrapper(api_key) as client:
        response1 = await client.get_endpoint1("argument1", "argument2")
        print(response1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: When modifying your example to just fetch the text response of Google (as your example doesn't work), I don't see any unclosed client sessions. The only warning I see is an unclosed transport, which is a bug in v3 that is explained at: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#graceful-shutdown

Comment: That's strange. I had to modify my code to post it here tho but I think I have set everything properly.  Can I see your example code and check it myself? Just to confirm, which aiohttp and Python versions are you using? Thank you.

My versions are Python 3.11 and aiohttp 3.9.3

Comment: ok, found out the issue. The file I was using instantiated the object twice. Its because I used this file as an example or demonstration which contained some statements (one of them instantiating the object without any user agent set, and the other one setting a user agent, but using the same variable name. When reating a new session on the same variable, it returns the unclosed client session warning. After doing proper debugging and removing one of the instances, everything works as normal. No unclosed transport error or any other error. Thank you!

Comment: So I thought that to fix this I could add a __del__ method if by any case the object gets instantiated again, but seems like `    async def __del__(self):
        await self.close()` will not work as you won't await the destruction of an object.

Comment: No, async code must be explicit, which is why we can't do proper cleanup on garbage collection. This is why we raise these warnings on garbage collection. See the aiohttp source code if you'd like to copy a similar warning into your code that mentions your custom class specifically.